# angular upgrade left me with lots of 'legacy' imports

Tags: angular

We have upgraded from Angular 11 to Angular 15. Amazingly, the upgrade went through smoothly, with the update process making all the required changes automatically.
However, I noticed it replaced all angular material imports with 'legacy', for example:

```
import { MatLegacyDialogModule as MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-dialog'
import { MatLegacyButtonModule as MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-button
import { MatLegacyPaginatorModule as MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-paginator'
```

I could not google any information on any of those legacy modules. What am I supposed to do about this? Leave as it is? Do something?

Comment: I am having one more issue with Legacy instances is that the theming is not working at all, and it couldn't load the angular theme file. Are you also facing the same issue?

Comment: Theming seems fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer that satisfies me here:

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/guides/v15-mdc-migration.md

Looks like Angular material got refactored with new a look&feel and the old ones got preserved as legacy-.

Comment: Hi @Ya. how did you do mdc migration, as it further leads to many issues like more unit test cases fail, ui will be broken, and themes will get affected. And there is no clear cut guide about mdc migration to refer actually. Its so crazy.

Comment: We worked through it piece by piece. Yep, no easy way out.

Comment: Hi @Ya. thanks for your reply, could you please let me know which documentation you referred to : is it https://m2.material.io/design or https://github.com/angular/components/tree/15.2.9/src/material?which should we refer to modify the v14 related angular material styles to mdc specific?